# Need correct if function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I need help with below formula.

If the difference in dates mentioned in cell A1 & B1 is 60 days, we need Manager approval, if its 90 days we need Sr. Manager approval, if more than 90 days we need VP approval.

I am using if function but not getting required output.

Comment: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`IF(B1-A1<=60,"Manager",IF(B1-A1<=90,"Sr. Manager","VP")`

I hope I understood your criteria well.